# Summing up cells value with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an Excel sheet file called 'f1-results.xlsx' with tabs named by races (countries names): Australia, China, Bahrain, Russia etc. Every tab contains standings in the following format:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | Sebastian Vettel VET | Ferrari | 1:24:11.672 | 25 |

First column (A) is the position (place after race), next one (B) is non-relevant, another one (C) contains names of the drivers (I need it) and column F contains points scored in this certain race (I need it too). It looks like this:

*Sheet (race) 'Australia'*:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | Sebastian Vettel VET | Ferrari | 1:24:11.672 | 25 |
| 2 | 44 | Lewis Hamilton HAM | Mercedes | +9.975s | 18 |
| 3 | 77 | Valtteri Bottas BOT | Mercedes | +11.250s | 15 |
| 4 | 7 | Kimi Räikkönen RAI | Ferrari | +22.393s | 12 |
| 5 | 33 | Max Verstappen VER | Red Bull Racing TAG Heuer | +28.827s | 10 |

*Sheet (race) 'China'*:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 44 | Lewis Hamilton HAM | Mercedes | 1:37:36.158 | 25 |
| 2 | 5 | Sebastian Vettel VET | Ferrari | +6.250s | 18 |
| 3 | 33 | Max Verstappen VER | Red Bull Racing TAG Heuer | +45.192s | 15 |
| 4 | 3 | Daniel Ricciardo RIC | Red Bull Racing TAG Heuer | +46.035s | 12 |
| 5 | 7 | Kimi Räikkönen RAI | Ferrari | +48.076s | 10 |
| 6 | 77 | Valtteri Bottas BOT | Mercedes | +48.808s | 8 |

Keep in mind that the drivers are listed in different order in every race.

Based on this file, I have to make a new xlsx file with sheet called 'Standings' which will present number of points after each race for each driver.

For example:

|  | Australia | China |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lewis Hamilton | 18 | 43 |

(because he has scored 18 points in Australia race and 25 in China, so 18+25)

Here's my code but I can't make it to sum up the points after each race.

Right now it displays it as below:

|  | Australia | China |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lewis Hamilton | 18 | 25 | 43 |

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook

# Load the workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='/kaggle/input/f1-results/f1-results.xlsx')

# Create a new workbook for standings
standings_workbook = Workbook()
standings_sheet = standings_workbook.active
standings_sheet.title = 'Standings'

# Initialize a dictionary to store points for each driver
driver_points = {}

# Iterate through each sheet (race)
for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
    # Get the current sheet
    race_sheet = wb[sheet_name]
    
    # Iterate through rows in the current sheet starting from 2nd row (excluding headers)
    for row in range(2, race_sheet.max_row + 1):
        # Extract driver name and points
        driver_name = race_sheet.cell(row=row, column=3).value
        points = race_sheet.cell(row=row, column=6).value
        
        # Update points for the driver
        if driver_name in driver_points:
            driver_points[driver_name][sheet_name] = points
        else:
            driver_points[driver_name] = {sheet_name: points}

# Write headers for each race
race_index = 2
for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
    standings_sheet.cell(row=1, column=race_index, value=sheet_name)
    race_index += 1

# Write driver names and points after each race
driver_index = 2
for driver, race_points in driver_points.items():
    standings_sheet.cell(row=driver_index, column=1, value=driver)
    
    race_index = 2
    for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
        points = race_points.get(sheet_name, 0)  # Get points for this race, or default to 0 if not found
        standings_sheet.cell(row=driver_index, column=race_index, value=points)
        race_index += 1
    
    driver_index += 1

# Sum up the points for each driver
for row in range(2, standings_sheet.max_row + 1):
    total_points = sum(int(standings_sheet.cell(row=row, column=col).value or 0) for col in range(2, standings_sheet.max_column + 1))
    standings_sheet.cell(row=row, column=standings_sheet.max_column + 1, value=total_points)

# Save the standings workbook
standings_workbook.save(filename='_driver_standings.xlsx')
```

I have no idea how to make it add the following cells to each other.

Comment: Can you try removing `+1` in `for` loop for columns when calculating `total_points` on end of script?

Comment: Someone else had exactly [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75420763/how-to-create-the-table-in-python) Is the spreadsheet available to download?

Comment: @MilosStojanovic that didn't work :/

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you wanna get a sequence of cumulative sums for each driver, kind of `[australia, australia+china, australia+china+europe, ...]` ?

Comment: @Vitalizzare yes, exactly this

Comment: You're really best off putting all the data into a database (or dataframe) and use a windowing function for the "points so far".

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does appear to be summing,
**BUT** the line when you write the total

```
standings_sheet.cell(row=row, column=standings_sheet.max_column + 1, value=total_points)
```

is going to shift a column each write. 
`standings_sheet.max_column` is the real-time last column every time its read.

For example for the first driver; 
If `standings_sheet.max_column` = 10 the total is written into Column 11 (Column K)
The last column or `standings_sheet.max_column` is now equal to 11.
Therefore on the next driver, with the last column being 11 it means `column=standings_sheet.max_column + 1` is now 12 so the total is writen to column 12 or Column L, and so on for all your drivers.

You want to read  'max_column' before the loop, add 1 and then use that one value for all your Drivers. 
Like;

```
totals_column = standings_sheet.max_column + 1
for row in range(2, standings_sheet.max_row + 1):
    total_points = sum(int(standings_sheet.cell(row=row, column=col).value or 0) for col in range(2, standings_sheet.max_column + 1))
    standings_sheet.cell(row=row, column=totals_column, value=total_points)
```

*** I downloaded test data for 2023 F1 from https://www.formula1.com and just tested with 3 of the races/countries.
Note the points were in column 7 for me rather than 6 but your data may be sourced from a different site or modified.
`points = race_sheet.cell(row=row, column=6).value`

However other than the above difference and the total column issue your code worked with the downloaded data.

**UPDATE**
If you want a cumulative total then you don't need any of that summing section at the end.
Add the totals as you create the driver_points dictionary. When the next country points are added to that dictionary also add the points from the previous Sheet for that driver.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook

# Load the workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='f1-results.xlsx')

# Create a new workbook for standings
standings_workbook = Workbook()
standings_sheet = standings_workbook.active
standings_sheet.title = 'Standings'

# Initialize a dictionary to store points for each driver
driver_points = {}

# Iterate through each sheet (race)
for idx, sheet_name in enumerate(wb.sheetnames):
    # Get the current sheet
    race_sheet = wb[sheet_name]

    # Iterate through rows in the current sheet starting from 2nd row (excluding headers)
    for row in range(2, race_sheet.max_row + 1):
        # Extract driver name and points
        driver_name = race_sheet.cell(row=row, column=3).value
        points = race_sheet.cell(row=row, column=6).value

        # Update points for the driver
        if driver_name in driver_points:
            # driver_points[driver_name][sheet_name] = points
            ### Get the points from the previous sheets for the driver and add to the current points
            driver_points[driver_name][sheet_name] = int(points) + driver_points[driver_name][wb.sheetnames[idx-1]]
        else:
            driver_points[driver_name] = {sheet_name: points}

# Write headers for each race
race_index = 2
for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
    standings_sheet.cell(row=1, column=race_index, value=sheet_name)
    race_index += 1

# Write driver names and points after each race
driver_index = 2
for driver, race_points in driver_points.items():
    standings_sheet.cell(row=driver_index, column=1, value=driver)

    race_index = 2
    for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
        points = race_points.get(sheet_name, 0)  # Get points for this race, or default to 0 if not found
        standings_sheet.cell(row=driver_index, column=race_index, value=points)
        race_index += 1

    driver_index += 1

standings_workbook.save(filename='_driver_standings.xlsx')
```

Comparison
*The image below is to show the points are added for each race. The resultant Sheet from the updated code will be only the second screen shot on the right.*
The first Excel screen shot shows the individual points for a selection of drivers over three races in three countries.
The second Excel screen shot (to the right) shows the cumulative total as each race is added.

**Note** the races/countries are not necessarily in actual real order, they are just random results copied to Excel for illustration and placed in the order shown.

[image]

Comment: thanks but I don't want 'total' column. I want to have standings with points summed up after each race, for example: Lewis Hamilton 18 | 43 (because he has scored 18 points in Australia race and 25 in China, so 18+25)